# Flash Builder 4 Design View vs Flash runtime appearance w/SDK 4.1

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash, flash-builder

- Flash Builder's design view is worse than 3's (which at least was usable if you ignore some quirks), so WHAT do Flex UI designers (those who don't have paid design teams...) do to design a **complex** UI?  Because Design View (also based on what a lot of people say about it..) gets more useless with every release.
- See image for some differences in design view vs. Flash. WHAT is causing this? css also posted.. ("Duration", "hr", "min" are mx Labels, the image size text is an mx Text comp. Project is an "mx only" SDK 4.1 project.)  I don't even care that the spinners look different, I just need it to show me correctly sized stuff so I can position things via Canvas, or properly size containers.

[image]

mx|Label {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12;
}

mx|Text {
    font-weight:normal;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try embedding your fonts.  I've found the design view to be more accurate when you do so.

But overall, the design view sucks.  I code most of my views by hand.  Flash Catalyst gives you pretty good fidelity, but it's an entirely different type of tool.

Comment: I've tried Catalyst and it just doesn't seem ready. Microsoft is way ahead with Blend 4 on this point. The silly thing here is that I'm just using the total default Arial font. After I posted I tried explicitly setting the font to Arial in css, for SOME reason that seems to have improved things vastly. I still don't think it's an exact match (also seems to be some issue with size and weight) but I can probably work with this. Design view is such a disappointment, I'd easily give up Spark just for better WYSIWYG w/Halo.

Comment: Yes, stay away from design view, it doesn't work. 
Good luck with that because design integration in Flex is a new job in itself :)

Comment: I don't understand what the rest of you people do then, when you're doing anything complex.  If you have to design your UI in mxml (code) purely, you're better off going back to the dark ages of jsp/jstl suffering.  **Usually** if I don't use odd fonts I don't have problems using design view, but sometimes (like here)... wtf?  I was able to resolve the issue by specifying the font info I wanted in "enough places" within the css, but still, it should be easier.

Comment: What does "coding most of your views by hand" mean anyway?  Copy/paste mxml manually and then start/run your app, navigate to the component in question (which may be buried in some complex workflow or whatever and hard to get to), test it, and repeat?  If that was my dev workflow I'd switch to Silverlight exclusively.